# n side of n-m relationship not storing in QField

Tags: qfield

I have an n-m relationship in QGIS which works fine. On QField, the N side of the relationship is not storing (later in attribute table the n_id is empty).

I have two geometry tables:

```
Structures (Point layer):
...
uuid
...
```

```
Pipe (Line layer):
...
uuid
...
```

```
join table
pipe_measurement (no geometry):
...
structure_id
pipe_id
...
```

I have two relationships defined (Composition):

```
Structures-uuid -2- pipe_measurement-structure_id
Pipe-uuid -2- pipe_measurement-pipe_id
```

On Structures, In the Attributes Form - Using Drag & Drop Designer - I have the relationship Structure_Measurement (first listed above) added to the form.

In QGIS when I create a new structure, and add a new measurement and save, it all works fine.

In Qfield - it appears to work on create new in that there is a unique string listed in the Structures drop down box. I choose the pipe I want, and save.

When I go back to edit that structure, there is no measurement associated with it.

When I edit a structure and add a measurement it again looks like it is working, but when I go back there is no measurement.

When I push the changes back to QGIS and look at the attribute table for measurements, the structure_id field is blank on every entry.

I attempted to set this up based on the QField documentation for adding multiple photos. Maybe I am missing something?